# What is the Ruby regex to match a string with at least one period and no spaces?

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the regex to match a string with at least one period and no spaces?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this :

```
/^\S*\.\S*$/
```

It works like this :

```
^    <-- Starts with
  \S   <-- Any character but white spaces (notice the upper case) (same as [^ \t\r\n])
  *    <-- Repeated but not mandatory
  \.   <--  A period
  \S   <-- Any character but white spaces
  *    <-- Repeated but not mandatory
$    <-- Ends here
```

You can replace `\S` by `[^ ]` to work strictly with spaces (not with tabs etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
 ^[^ ]*\.[^ ]*$
```

(match any non-spaces, then a period, then some more non-spaces)

Answer (score 2):

no need regular expression. Keep it simple

```
>> s="test.txt"
=> "test.txt"
>> s["."] and s.count(" ")<1
=> true
>> s="test with spaces.txt"
=> "test with spaces.txt"
>> s["."] and s.count(" ")<1
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^\S*\.\S*$/
```